# Email adress as <input value=""> gives weird javascript code

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I am trying to create a pre-filled HTML form with an email address in it using the following code:

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
Email: <input type="text" name="email" size="20" maxlength="255" value="<?php     echo($row['email']) ?>"/> <br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" /></p>
</form>
```

When echoing `$row['email']` outside of the textbox I get an hyperlinked mailto:[the-email-adress] which is fine, but when I try to use the email ad a prefiller I get this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> <!-- var prefix = 'ma' + 'il' + 'to'; var path = 'hr' + 'ef' + '='; var addy63669 = 'MYGOOGLENAME' + '@'; addy63669 = addy63669 + 'gmail' + '.' + 'com'; document.write('<a ' + path + '\'' + prefix + ':' + addy63669 + '\'>'); document.write(addy63669); document.write('<\/a>'); //-->\n </script><script type='text/javascript'> <!-- document.write('<span style=\'display: none;\'>'); //--> </script>This email address is being protected from spambots. You need JavaScript enabled to view it. <script type='text/javascript'> <!-- document.write('</'); document.write('span>'); //--> </script>
```

Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Are you using Joomla's e-mail cloaking plug-in, perhaps? Seems like something is mutilating your `mailto:` links; it's definitely not default behavior of PHP or the browser, unless you've got a plug-in running that's doing it.

Comment: Thats it, I was indeed running that plugin.